# Number of hql query excuting in a code

Tags: hql

How many queries are excuted in the follwing code?

```
   Customer c=(Customer)session.createQuery(“from Customer c where  c.customer_id=:Id”).setParameter(“Id”,222).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only one squ\l query like below:

```
select * from Customer c 
where  c.customer_id= 222
```

Plus hiberanate's uniqueResult() validate result set for **rows == 1**. It is not done at db side.

> uniqueResult() is a Convenience method to return a single instance
>   that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.